# How can I create a group of everyone who gave in honor of a specific person?

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

I can see a list of everyone who gave in honor of a specific person by looking at that contact's Contributions tab (under Soft Credits).  However, I can't figure out how to put these folks into a group, or even generate a report on them to see their contact info.  How do I do this?

Comment: I can see that the "Soft Credit Report" allows me to search by "Soft Credit Name" - this is the direction I want, but I need to send a postal mailing to these folks, and the postal address isn't in this report.

Comment: Did you check using Views?

Comment: Can you create a Group "Soft Credit Smith", Run the "Soft Credit Report" to get the list of contacts you want, then over the right "+ Add Contacts To Group". Then do a mailing for that Group?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an extension [Soft Credit Custom Fields](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.softcreditcustomfields) which, amongst other things, adds a "Soft Creditee's Name" field to the Advanced Search.

Answer (score 1):

With SearchKit it's possible to create the smart group without the help of the extension:

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Fundraisers_P2P",
          "label": "Fundraisers P2P",
          "api_entity": "Contact",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "sort_name",
              "contact_type:label",
              "contact_sub_type:label",
              "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.soft_credit_type_id:label) AS GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01_soft_credit_type_id_label"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [
              [
                "Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.soft_credit_type_id:name",
                "=",
                "pcp"
              ]
            ],
            "groupBy": [
              "id"
            ],
            "join": [
              [
                "ContributionSoft AS Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01",
                "INNER",
                [
                  "id",
                  "=",
                  "Contact_ContributionSoft_contact_id_01.contact_id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```